# Getting a specific field in a MySQL database with Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a bank account program in Java to test out MySQL. So far the program lets you make a new member with First and Last name, a password, userid, and account balance (each user takes up one row in the database). How would you let them log in just by entering their userid and password? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to show a bit of effort in order for us to help you better. Show how you're attempting to authenticate; provide more details (GUI, console, web, etc.), and more importantly, give it a shot yourself and let us know what's *not* working.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to compare the given credential access with the values on the database.

You may want to store a hashed password (with salt!) in order to prevent problems if the db is stolen.

The idea of salting the hash is important, there are hashing functions as md5 that are known not to be secure, however if you do this

```
password = "123456"
salt = "someString" //Anything you want, but it must be the same all the time
saltedPassword = password + "-" + salt
hashedSaltedPassword = yourHashFunction(saltedPassword)
```

Then, hashedSaltedPassword is safer, as if the hash function is broken the password the attackant will get will be "123456-someString" which is not the real password.

The hashing functions fields is pretty interesting, I strongly suggest you to look into it, anyway start by looking at the SHA functions

In any case, looks like you should search google a little bit :)

Comment: I was thinking about storing a hashed password but this is just for testing purposes. I don't know the code to compare the password with the database values.

Comment: I finally figured out the MySQL query to do this. Juan how would you go about storing hashed passwords.